# Replacing Inner Arrays in a 2D Array Recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to recursively loop through a 2D array and replace an inner array each time. The problem is that no array seems to be created. Trying to access a value in the array makes java complain that the index used is out-of-bounds.

How can I replace inner arrays in a 2D array using recursion?

I have to replace the arrays dynamically because I want the 2D array to be ragged. Each index should hold an array whose length equals it's index number + 1.

**How I call my method:**

```
double[][] personArr = new double[5][];
personArr = personArrCreator(personArr, 0);
```

**My method:**

```
/**
 * Creates a ragged, pyramid-shaped, 2d array
 * @param pArr The blank 2d Array to fill out
 * @param num Controls the base case.
 * @return double[][] The finished 2d array
 */
 private static double[][] personArrCreator(double[][] pArr, int num) {
    pArr[num] = new double[num];

    if (num == 4) {
       return pArr;
    }

    personArrCreator(pArr, num + 1);
    return null; // never called
 }
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it does not produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (or any other exception).

Comment: @JoeC What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK 11. But that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JoeC Did you try to access any inner values in the array?

Comment: No, because the method is returning `null`, and I therefore knew there was no array to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return null; // never called
```

This actually is called, as once the base case is reached, all the other methods will return null. Instead you want to return the results of the method, by resolving what the recursive call returns to the `Array`:

```
return personArrCreator(pArr, num + 1);
```

Which will return:

```
[[], [0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Which will return an `Array` of size zero. I dont think this is what you want. Instead you could initialize the size as `num + 1` to fix this:

```
private static double[][] personArrCreator(double[][] pArr, int num) {
   pArr[num] = new double[num + 1];
   if (num == 4) {
      return pArr;
   }
   return personArrCreator(pArr, num + 1);
}
```

Which produces the `Array`:

```
[[0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`personArr = personArrCreator(personArr, 0);` resolves to null, because `return null; // never called` is not true, this will in fact be called 4 times as you go back up the recursive stack.

After `personArrCreator(pArr, 4);` returns `pArr`, nothing is done with this and instead `null` is returned. That is because the `personArrCreator(pArr, 4);` return will return to the previous recursion call, not to the initial function call.

If you want to do this recursively (you can also do this with a loop), try

```
return pArr;
```